# How do I recreate the effect of scratching a scratchcard in Python? (remove a layer gradually in order to reveal a picture underneath?)

Tags: python, image, pygame, sprite, transparency

I've made a moving sprite using the Pygame module. It moves around the screen changing directions when it hits the screen border. I want to gradually reveal a picture as if the sprite was a coin scratching the front image of a scratchcard away to reveal a picture underneath. So far I've made a lot of small squaresized white sprites, that cover the screen and are removed upon colliding with the moving sprite. This works okay, but gives the transition a pixelated look. I'm almost certain this would work if I could make enough small sprites, but its very computer intensive and there must be another way to achieve the same effect. (It is my first post. I hope the code is readable and formatted properly. Thank you for reading:))

```
`import pygame, sys
import random
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen_width, screen_height = 800, 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

pic_path = "absolute path"
BG_Pic = "BGIMG0.png"
Background_picture = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(pic_path + BG_Pic),(800, 800))
Background_picture_rect = Background_picture.get_rect()

###CLASSES###
class Moving_rect(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, widthheight, x_speed, y_speed):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface([widthheight, widthheight])
        self.image.fill((87, 161, 230))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(centerx = x, centery = y)
        self.x_speed = x_speed
        self.y_speed = y_speed

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))
    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.x_speed
        self.rect.y += self.y_speed
        if self.rect.right >= screen_width+0.5 or self.rect.left <= -0.5:
            self.x_speed *= -1
        if self.rect.bottom >= screen_height+0.5 or self.rect.top <= -0.5:
            self.y_speed *= -1

class BG_rect(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, color):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill((color))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (x,y))


    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))

####CLASSES####

Number_of_cubes = 1

block = pygame.sprite.Group()

for cube in range(0,Number_of_cubes):
    cube_x = random.randint(0, 480)
    cube_y = random.randint(0, 720)

    block.add(Moving_rect(cube_x,
                           cube_y,
                          20,
                          2,
                           2))

number_of_rects_pr_side= 100
other_rect_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

for i in range(0,number_of_rects_pr_side):
    for k in range(0,number_of_rects_pr_side):
        other_rect_group.add(BG_rect(k * (800/number_of_rects_pr_side)
                                        , i * (800/number_of_rects_pr_side)
                                        , (800 / number_of_rects_pr_side),
                                        (800 / number_of_rects_pr_side)
                                        , (255, 255, 255)))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.QUIT()
            sys.exit()
    screen.blit(Background_picture, Background_picture_rect)
    pygame.sprite.groupcollide(other_rect_group, block, True, False)
    block.update()
    block.draw(screen)
    other_rect_group.update()
    other_rect_group.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(20)
```

`

Comment: How about making a solid surface and painting with transparency?

Answer (score -1):

`So far I've made a lot of small squaresized white sprites, that cover the screen and are removed upon colliding with the moving sprite. This works okay, but gives the transition a pixelated look. I'm almost certain this would work if I could make enough small sprites`

Indeed, that's not the way you wanna do this ^^

I would advise to use a mask. Basically, create a black image, and just draw a white line when the "scratch" point moves, using `pygame.draw.line()` (see doc [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.line)). `start_pos` and `end_pos` would be the scratch position before and after moving, for each iteration. `width` would be the scratch size. That way you can move as fast as you want (long jump) without multiplying cost.

You will end up with your result, in a black and white image, for a very cheap CPU usage. Then, just before draw calls, you would just use the mask to render your result (see [mask docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html)). Basically you would have one image replacing the dark part of the mask, and another image replacing the white part

Comment: Hi Tricotou! Thank you very much for your answer. I'm having having trouble having one image replacing the dark part and another image replacing the white. Would be so kind as to explain:)